# Add new iOS app to Crashlytics Beta via command line

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

Our CI system automatically creates *new* apps and uploads them to Crashlytics Beta using the command :
`./Crashlytics.framework/submit $CRASHLYTICS_API_KEY $CRASHLYTICS_BUILD_SECRET -ipaPath $IPA_PATH`

This all works fine when the app has already been activated in Crashlytics. But to activate an app in Crashlytics I have to open the Crashlytics website and run the iOS app in the simulator.

If the app isn't activated then we get the error:

`Unable to add testers: Project my-project is inactive`

Is there any way to add/activate a new app to Crashlyics beta in an automated way?

Comment: I've posted your question on Crashlytics forum: https://twittercommunity.com/t/add-new-ios-app-to-crashlytics-beta-via-command-line/56620

Comment: Thanks @FelipeCypriano

Answer (score 2):

> Hey @fcy,
>
> Awesome question. Currently for an app to be added to Crashlytics and
>   Fabric, we need to see both a build of the app and run of the event
>   for it to be active. We do this to prevent apps from being
>   automatically added by jail broken or rooted devices.
>
> However, we have been thinking about adding a build only onboarding. I
>   can keep you updated on this if you would like.
>
> -Mike

https://twittercommunity.com/t/add-new-ios-app-to-crashlytics-beta-via-command-line/56620

Comment: Worth a shot, was this ever updated? Linked thread shows no updates. Weak. I'm planning on moving us off Fabric for the same reason. Much to hard to automate.